# My React state doesn't stay on my components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code, I use a click event on the InterestBox in order to update the appearance of the InterestBox and to change the state of the parent of the parent of InterestBox.

However, when I inspect the element with the React Developer Tools or that I try to send a request to my API, the state.interests is always empty. But, when I log the state in the console, it shows an array with a length of 0, but containing all the proper values.

I tried to find what is wrong with my code, but I think I need an external look to find what is wrong.

````
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '../../components/Button';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard';
import ErrorContainer from '../../components/ErrorContainer';
import InterestList from '../../components/register/InterestList';

export class EditUser extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {loading: true, interests: []}
        this.addInterest = this.addInterest.bind(this);
        this.logState = this.logState.bind(this);
    }

    addInterest(id, name) {
        console.log('hoppity hippity you parenty')
        var mid = 'm' + id;
        console.log(this.state.interests[mid] == undefined)

        if(this.state.interests[mid] == undefined) {
            console.log(this.state);
            this.setState((state) => {
                state.interests[mid] = name;
                return {interests: state.interests}
            }, () => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.interests))
            })
        } else {
            console.log('deleted')
            var newInterest = this.state.interests;
            delete newInterest[mid]
            this.setState({interests: newInterest})
        }
        console.log(this.state.interests)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var token = Cookies.get('token');
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/details', {headers: {"Accept": 'application/json', "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}}).then(
            (success) => {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    firstname : success.data.data.user.firstname, 
                    lastname: success.data.data.user.lastname, 
                    email: success.data.data.user.email,
                    dob: success.data.data.user.dob,
                    address: success.data.data.user.address,
                    uinterests: success.data.data.interests
                })
            }, (error) => {
                this.props.history.push('/deconnexion');
            }
        )
        var places = require('places.js');
        var placesAutocomplete = places({
        appId: "plZJLSHIW8M5",
        apiKey: "0eddd2fc93b5429f5012ee49bcf8807a",
        container: document.querySelector('#address-input')
        });
    }

    logState() {
        console.log(this.state);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Dashboard loading={this.state.loading}>
                <h1 className="title">Modifier mon profil</h1>
                <form className="user-form offer-update-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>Prénom :</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" value={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.handleChange}></input> <br />
                <label>Nom de famille :</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" value={this.state.lastname} onChange={this.handleChange}></input> <br />
                <label>Email :</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                <label>Adresse :</label>
                <input type="address" id="address-input" name="address" value={this.state.address} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                <label>Date de naissance :</label>
                <input type="date" name="dob" value={this.state.dob} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                <InterestList alreadyChecked={this.state.uinterests} onClick={this.addInterest} />
                <ErrorContainer errors={this.state.errors} />
                <Button type="primary">Soumettre les changements</Button>
                </form>
                <Button type="danger" onClick={this.logState} />
            </Dashboard>
        )
    }
}

export default EditUser
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import InterestBox from './InterestBox'
import Axios from 'axios'

export class InterestList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {pinterests: []}
        this.pinterestRefs = React.createRef()
        this.pinterestRefs.current = [];
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/interests')
        .then((success) => {
            this.setState({pinterests: success.data.data.interests});
        })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(prevProps));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props))
        if(this.props.alreadyChecked != prevProps.alreadyChecked) {
            this.props.alreadyChecked.forEach((item) => {
                this.pinterestRefs.current.forEach((pinterest) => {
                    if(item == pinterest.props.id) {
                        console.log(pinterest)
                        pinterest.handleClick();
                    }
                })
                console.log(item)
            })
        }
        console.log(this.pin)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {Object.keys(this.state.pinterests).map((interest, i) => {
                    var pinterest = this.state.pinterests[interest];
                    var callbackRef = node => this.pinterestRefs.current[i] = node;
                    return <InterestBox id={pinterest.id} onClick={this.props.onClick} icon={pinterest.picture_src} title={pinterest.name} ref={callbackRef} />
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default InterestList
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export class InterestBox extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.images = require('../../img/interests/*.svg');

        this.state = {activated: false};
        this.interest_box_content = React.createRef();
        this.interest_text = React.createRef();
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.updateDimensions = this.updateDimensions.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        console.log('hoppity hippity you clicky')
        this.props.onClick(this.props.id, this.props.title);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            activated: !prevState.activated
        }))        
    }

    updateDimensions() {
        console.log((window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.interest_box_content).width))
        this.refs.interest_text = (window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.interest_box_content).width)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="column is-one-fifth-desktop is-half-touch">
                <div className="interest-box">
                    <div className="interest-box-adjuster">
                        <div ref={"interest_box_content"} className={"interest-box-content " + (this.state.activated == true ? 'interest-box-activated' : '')} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <img className="interest-icon" src={this.images[this.props.icon]} style={{'height': '50%'}}></img>
                            <i className="activated-icon fas fa-check"></i>
                            <span ref={"interest_text"} className="interest-text">{this.props.title}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default InterestBox

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have initialized interest as an array using []

but then, you are updating it as a map `state.interests[mid] = name;`

**Note: JS is not type-safe. after the above statement, interests no longer remained an array**

That's the reason why on console you are able to see it being populated but with an array length of 0. that's because you are outputting an object now and not an array.

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! 
However, just for clarification, why didn't the state just turn into an object instead of getting back to array ?

Comment: I think I get it now.
I was just wondering why instead of getting stuck it didn't become an object. Like, if I make a var n and give it the value "hello", but then I do n = 10, the value of n should be 10, not "hello". I was wondering why it wasn't the same for this case.

Comment: well, wasn't it ? you have no operation of reassigning an array to `interests` (Although it's not an appropriate way to use ur variables), if u had one, it would have became an array again.